# Looping for creating graphs

Tags: python, loops, pandas, graphing

I am seeking some guidance on how to best automate a loop to create graphical visualization of some calculations made from dict.

I've pieced together the following code to create a single graph, but need to produce many similar graphs (using different variables) and would rather not type out each variable multiple times (there will be 100s of variables).

For a single graph, I have the following code (see below) where Calclist is a dict and variable1 is a specific column within that dict:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 Sets = {}
 labels = ['0 - 5','5 - 25','25 - 50','50 - 75','75 - 100']
 blocks = [-1,5,25,50,75,100]

 for i in Calclist:

     out = pd.cut(Calclist[i]['variable1'], bins = blocks)
     Sets[i] = (pd.value_counts(out)/Calclist[i]['variable1'].count())*100

 df = pd.DataFrame(Sets)
 df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
 df.rename(index = str, columns = {'index':'blocks'}, inplace=True)

 ax = df.plot.bar(title='One iteration - works well')
 ax.set_xlabel("x-axis label")
 ax.set_ylabel("y-axis label")
 ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)
```

So far, so good - this is what the code will produce:

[image: Single iteration]

**What I would really like to do is iterate through variable1 (to variable2, variable3, .....).**

I have tried a couple of things, and think I'm close but likely missing something fundamental.

Specifically, I tried nesting another loop that iterates over a series using "Parameter", which holds the variable names that I'm interested in visualizing:

```
 Sets = {}
 labels = ['0 - 5','5 - 25','25 - 50','50 - 75','75 - 100']    
 blocks = [-1,5,25,50,75,100]                                

 Parameter = pd.Series("variable1","variable2")

 for j in Parameter:

     for i in Calclist:

         out = pd.cut(Calclist[i][Parameter[j]], bins = blocks)
         Sets[i] = (pd.value_counts(out)/Calclist[i]
         [Parameter[j]].count())*100
```

but I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 
 'powertotal_total' was passed
```

Any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: your code is not really reproducable because you don't give example data for `Calclist`... if you could update your code with dummy `Calclist` that would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is caused by the way you are initializing `Parameters`:

```
parameter = pd.Series('variable1', 'variable2')
...
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind,
'variable2' was passed
```

You must pass *array-like, dict, or scalar value* to [`pd.Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html). Also, iterating over `Parameters` will return its values. Finally, you should initialize `Sets` for each `parameter`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['0 - 5','5 - 25','25 - 50','50 - 75','75 - 100']
blocks = [-1,5,25,50,75,100]

Parameters = pd.Series(['variable1', 'variable2'])

for parameter in Parameters:
    Sets = {}
    for i in Calclist:
        out = pd.cut(Calclist[i][parameter], bins = blocks)
        Sets[i] = (pd.value_counts(out)/Calclist[i][parameter].count())*100

    df = pd.DataFrame(Sets)
    df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
    df.rename(index=str, columns={'index': 'blocks'}, inplace=True)

    ax = df.plot.bar(title=parameter)
    ax.set_xlabel("x-axis label")
    ax.set_ylabel("y-axis label")
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, especially if I remove the plotting from the Calclist loop (via backspace). Thank you for the help with the code as well as the education on pd.Series.

Comment: I changed the code so that the plotting is outside the Calclist loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate over the pandas series in that way.
Try

```
for j in ["variable1","variable2"]:
```

or some variation of that

edit: or look up how to iterate over a pandas series
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html